# Multi select dropdown select all

Tags: php, codeigniter, drop-down-menu, multi-select

Here is my Controller function and view of multi select dropdown.How can i include 'all' condition to select all data that are in multselect dropdown .Please Help me

Controller Function

```
$where2 = array('departments.isDeleted =' => 0);
        $data['dept'] = $this->general_model->get('departments',$where2);
```

View:

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Departments</label
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <select name="departmentId[]" class="form-control" multiple="multiple" id="departmentId" >
            <?php if(is_array($dept)){ foreach($dept as $depts){ ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $depts['departmentId'];?>">
                   <?php echo $depts['departmentName'];?>
                 </option>
             <?php   }} ?>
        </select>
     </div>
</div><!--/form-group-->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before `<?php if(is_array($dept)){ foreach($dept as $depts){ ?>`

add `<option value="all">All</option>`

Sometimes the easiest solutions are the least apparent ;)

Note: you could make it so that (with js) when the "all" option is selected the rest are deselected for better ui but it really doesn't matter. On the backend you can just have a condition checking for `all` as selected and disregard the rest that are selected (because you have `multiple` enabled).

Comment: Where should i apply if ($val == 'all') condition

Comment: Presumably this is going in some database right? Or for a search or whatever. So you can just do `$deptid = $this->input->post('departmentId'); if (in_array('all', $deptid)) { /*all selected*/ } else { /*specific values selected */ }` make sense?